# How to provide an array in IN clause presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, in-clause

I have the following query

```
select * 
from Table1 
where NUMid in (select array_agg(NUMid) 
                from Table2 
                where email = 'xyz@gmail.com')
```

My intention is to get the list of all the NUMids from table2 having an email value equal to xyz@gmail.com and use those list of NUMids to query from Table1.

But I am getting the following error:

> value and result of subquery must be of the same type for IN expression: bigint vs array(bigint)

Basically `IN` clause cannot take in an array. Is there workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you don't even need to call `ARRAY_AGG` here, just use a standard `WHERE IN (...)` construct:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE NUMid IN (SELECT NUMid FROM Table2 WHERE email = 'xyz@gmail.com');
```

You could also phrase this using exists logic, for a possible performance enhancement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
              WHERE t2.NUMid = t1.NUMid AND t2.email = 'xyz@gmail.com');
```